# 2 databases with the same name exist in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I've got a problem connecting to my Database.  I get this error

```
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\RegisterDb\App_Data\RegisterDb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

Here is my web.config

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data 
         Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RegisterDb.mdf;Integrated 
                 Security=True;User Instance=True" 
                 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add name="DdExamen2ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=
        (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RegisterDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

here is the Register.designer.cs

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="RegisterDb")]
public partial class RegistersDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{

private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new 
        AttributeMappingSource();


       base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
           ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
```

I don't see what I am missing?

When I am looking at the Registers.dbml file, I saw the Connection : RegisterConnectionString(WebConfig)   and the connection String is  Data Source=(LocalDb)....
I am pretty sure this is the problem.   Anyone know how to recreate the ConnectionString ?

I saw 2 files in the web.config file for the connectionString ?  What I did wrong?

Comment: Make sure its is not already attached in management studio

Comment: @meda  I saw two ConnectionString in the web.config.  How I can rid of the local one ?  If I take it out I got also errors

Comment: @meda when I a going to my SqlDataSource in the Choose your Data Connection the choice are Custom or RegisterConnectionString.  Why it is not only ConnectionString ?

Comment: it means you had created a connection using visualstudio's wizard thats why

Comment: @meda with the SQLDataSource no needs to go to the wizard and set it up there ?  If I go back in the designer.cs I still see the RegisterConnectionString.  I am pretty sure it should be just ConnectionString no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a connection string in you application, use the same one for all connections to the same database.

remove

```
  <add name="DdExamen2ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=
    (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RegisterDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: @mena I removed it now I get this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object   public CommentairesDataContext() : 
Line 38:    base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DdExamen2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
This is coming from the designer.cs file. If I change the name to remove the DbExamen2  it fail with the same error I mentionned at the description of the thread An attempt to attach an auto....

Comment: @user3127986 replace them all with `ConnectionString`

Comment: I removed what you said and I deleted the database also.  I recreated the database and now the StringConnection is fine in the description.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have used 2 connection strings. Remove one of them. Most probably the second connection string should b deleted. as you are working on your own machine and .\SQLEXPRESS is simplest way to connect to your server. Remove the second one....